# 2001 Subaru Legacy L Wagon - Gas smell and light shaking

Tags: subaru, power, smell, legacy, gasoline

So... It is really freezing and has been really cold these past few days. 
But, my 2001 Subaru Legacy L Wagon started acting up.

First, here are things I know been replaced before I got it - Tires, Brakes, and Catalytic Converter. During this past year I have replaced (in a shop) the spark plugs and wires as part of a tune up. The tension belts - and been told that the timing belt seems fairly new.

So, about a week ago the car starting showing interesting behaviour. It started on a cold day, there was a strong gas smell coming from the AC. I drove around all day, and by the end of the day I tightened all the bolts and screws I saw - and I guess for most of the fuel line. (did it after reading [this](http://www.bazoomer.com/fuelline/fuelline.html)). Then I noticed a loose rubber hose. It was old, and cracked at the end. I tightened it with a zip tie, then drove to Auto Zone and got a rubber replacement and also tightened it with plastic zip ties. The attached picture shows the rubber hose (circled in red) - and it is the passanger side - just infront of the filter. What is this rubber hose for?

It seemed the smell went away, but yesterday and today (really freezing) the smell came back when idling at red lights or stop signs and the heat is on.

The second weird behaviour that I have experinced is what I can call as momentary power loss. Happened when I am starting to drive from standing at red light, stop sign, or in traffic - the car is vibrating more than usual - then lights and radio are killed and within a second or so are back - the radio is reset as if lost battery power (time and settings are reset). And today, for the first time, the car also jerked when it happened - but then recovered and kept on going.

So, my questions are:

1. Does anyone knows what is that rubber hose is?
2. Any ideas where the gas smell comes from? How much will it cost (roughly) to replace/fix all the fuel lines?

What can cause the power loss?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be related: [Possible reasons for loss of power, engine shaking, and smell of liquid fuel (not burning](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/6296), maybe duplicate.

Comment: The hose that you've circled is connected to the intake manifold at the top, and to the injector line at the bottom, right? If so, it's the [fuel pressure regulator](https://www.google.com/search?q=subaru+fuel+pressure+regulator) vacuum hose. As far as I know, there shouldn't be any fuel in that hose, so I don't think it'll have anything to do with the fuel smell. However, if the regulator is damaged for some reason, I suppose there could be fuel in there; the regulator itself could also be directly responsible for the smell.

Comment: When you smell the gas smell, find a safe place to pull over, get out and see if you can locate the smell under the hood.  I've had really good luck smelling out leaking fluids in the past (especially for something pungent like fuel).  NOTE: if you're investigating a running engine, make *certain* that none of your outfit is loose.  You don't want your scarf to end up in your serpentine belt....

Comment: @JoshCaswell, from reading the cited question and answer, I don't think the problem or solution is the same.  If nothing else, the other problem required replacing a coil vs. the rubber hose discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at part of your problem... This is a known issue.  I have highlighted the fuel line.  Looks like the line at the front of the engine is dark (leaking) fuel.  No fuel can equal power loss.  Replace and test drive.

[image]

Comment: Same problem on my 2001 OB.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: That was one of 2 issues for ours.  But yes.  We had a bad hose to the fuel filter as well.

Comment: Did you do it your self? If not, how much did you pay? If yes, where did you get the hoses? How much were they? What type/brand?

Comment: I did it myself yes.  Hoses were available at my local parts store.  Just took in the old stuff and they matched it. (If you don't have 2 cars, just drive it down there and point to it.  They should be able to match it.)